# MSCRM 2011 Javascript condition issue

Tags: javascript, if-statement, dynamics-crm

I have a problem with putting condition on javascript.
In case form I'm using below code. When i enter material code manually everything is ok but when i use search help it gives me an error. When i check it on debugger i see 2 situations based on my method of entering code.
Can you help me to improve my code below, its not working properly.
Gives me error on step `if (lookuptextvalue.name_Value.value)`if i enter material code using search help.

```
function matName() {
var lookupObject = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_material");

if (lookupObject != null)
{
    var lookUpObjectValue = lookupObject.getValue();
    if ((lookUpObjectValue != null))
    {
     var lookuptextvalue = lookUpObjectValue[0].keyValues;
     if (lookuptextvalue.name_Value.value) {
     var lookuptextvaluex = lookUpObjectValue[0].keyValues.name_Value.value;
     }
     else if(lookuptextvalue.name.value) {
     var lookuptextvaluex = lookUpObjectValue[0].keyValues.name.value;
     }
     var lookupid = lookUpObjectValue[0].id;

     Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_matname").setValue(lookuptextvaluex);
    }
    else {
     Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_matname").setValue();
}
}
}
```

Thanks Elda.

Comment: `lookuptextvalue.name_Value` does not exist but you are trying to find a property of it, this will throw an error. To fix first check it exists then check that the value equates to true `if ( lookuptextvalue.name_Value && lookuptextvalue.name_Value.value ){`
BTW you should take some time learning a good code layout style, yours is messy and having bad style will make it very hard to find bugs and problems as your code gets more complex.

Comment: @Blindman67 thakns for your advice and solution. It worked. Can you give me some links for learning ?

Comment: Look up Douglas Crockford, he has youtube seminars and lectures, books and much more. He created JSON, and JSLint. His ways may seem a little pedantic at first but well worth learning.  Good code style is so very important, personally it is the most important part to becoming a good programmer.

Answer (score 0):

This is such a common error that gets people new to javascript.

```
if(this.myData.myValue){ ...
// throws: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'myValue' of undefined`
```

Many will look at `myValue` for the problem but if you read the error carefully it is saying it can not find the property `myValue` of undefined. It is not `myValue` that is the issue but `myData` that is not defined and hence can not have any properties. I personly would like the error to read `Uncaught TypeError: 'myData' is undefined and has no property 'myValue'` as this would stop so many getting stuck on where the problem is.

`undefined` is a special object in javascript and crops up everywhere. `undefined` is equivalent to false. `undefined` is assigned to a object that is not initiated. Objects that have not been defined are equal to `undefined`. Object that have the value `undefined` are not placed in JSON files. `undefined` is not allowed in JSON files unless it is a string. Object that have the value `undefined` can not have properties. `undefined` is a primitive type.

Examples

```
var myObj; // declare a variable without a value. It automatically gets undefined
           // you can check if the object has a value

if(myObj === undefined){ // will be true if myObj has no value
                         // this does not mean it has been declare

if(myOtherObj === undefined){ // will return true as well even thought myOtherObj has not been declared
```

To check if a variable has been declared use void 0

```
// from above code snippet
if(myObj === void 0){ // is true because myObj has been declared

if(myOtherObj === void 0){ // is false because myOtherObj has not been declared.
```

Many people use the sort cut to determine if an object is undefined. This can cause problems if you are not careful.

```
if(!myObj){  // will be true if my object is undefined.
             // this is bad practice because the Numbers 0, the boolean false, 
             // the Object null are also equivalent to false;

myObj = 0
if(!myObj){ // the test intended to find out if myObj has been defined fails

myObj = false
if(!myObj){ // again the test fails.

myObj = null
if(!myObj){ // again.
```

I always insist that people use the exact equivalence operator `===` to test for `undefined`

```
if(myObj === undefined){
```

Unlike C/C++ and other similar languages the order of a conditional statement is always left to right. JavaScript will exit the conditional statment as soon as it knows that it has failed. This is handy for testing for undefined

The following is also the solution to the question.

```
var myObj;
if(myObj !== undefined && myObj.myProperty){ // this will not crash
                                             // because if myObj is undefined
                                             // it will exit at the first
                                             // condition.

// on the other hand this will
if(myObj.myProperty && myObj !== undefined){ // this will throw an error if 
                                             // myObj is undefined
```

`undefined` is equivalent to some other javascipt types

```
undefined == null   // true
undefined == false  // false
undefined == 0      // false
undefined === null  // false
undefined === false // false
undefined === 0     // false

// be careful as the ! operator changes things a little
var a = undefined;
!a //true
a = 0;
!a // true
a = null;
!a // true
a = false;    
!a // true
```

JSON files can not have undefined as a value.

```
{
    "myObj" : undefined
}
// this is not a valid JSON file.
```

When stringifing an object to JSON all objects that have the value undefined will not be added to the JSON string

```
var myObj = {
     propA : 0,
     propB : "hello",
     propC : undefined,
     propD : null
};
var str = JSON.stringify(myObj); // will create the JSON string

{
     "propA" : 0,
     "propB" : "hello",
     "propD" : null
}
// not that propC does not appear in the JSON
```

`undefined` is a complicated beast in JavaScript and it is best to become familiar with its uses.

Learn more at

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined